# Need help resizing this HTML frame

Tags: html, frames, frameset

Ok so I've NEVER worked with frames before but a higher power has forced my hand this time.

What I need to be able to do is resize the 'footer.html' frame within this template.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Store Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<frameset cols="*,1034,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
<frame name="sideblanks" scrolling="NO" src="blank_left.html">

<frameset rows="135,*,25" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
<frame name="top" scrolling="NO" noresize src="top_nav.html" >
<frameset cols="200,*" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0"> 
<frame name="meny" noresize scrolling="NO" src="menu_1.html">

<frame name="content" src="content.html">
</frameset>

<frame name="chart" scrolling="NO" noresize src="footer.html">

</frameset>
<frame name="sideblanks" scrolling="NO" src="blank_right.html">
</frameset>
<noframes>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">
</body>
</noframes> 
</html>
```

I feel like a complete novice again. I don't like it, I'm scared.

Any help would be great.

Comment: I should point out that I just need to increase the height of the frame and not the width

Comment: cant you use a css rule to resize the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the numeric values here:

```
<frameset rows="135,*,25" frameborder="NO" border="0" framespacing="0">
```

Comment: Great. please click the big checkmark on the left to select this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have used "rows" and "columns" you can set the height of the frame with rows or with CSS.

if you need to dynamically alter the height of the frame you might be able to do this with javascript or JQuery but you have to reference it as parent. to make sure you are in the right window.

when are you wanting the height of the frame to change?